# csv writer pad with zeroes

Tags: python, csv

I have a working python script that takes a .csv input, takes out the 4 columns that I want, trims all white space, and writes it to a new file.  There's only one thing I can't figure out how to do...

```
import csv,time,string,os,requests
dw = "\\\\network\\folder\\btc.csv"

inv_fields = ["id", "rsl", "number", "color_b4"]

with open(dw) as infile, open("c:\\upload\\log.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, inv_fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    r = (dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in r)

    wtr = csv.writer( outfile )
    wtr.writerow(["id", "resale", "number", "favorite_color"])
    for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
        row['id'] = i
        w.writerow(row)

print "file successfully saved"
```

I need to modify the 3rd column, `number`, either when the input file is being read, or when the output file is being written, so that each value is 9 digits long, padded with zeroes to the left.  The input will never be greater than 9, so:

Output:

```
Input      |    Output
1234       |    000001234
393939392  |    393939392
5          |    000000005
```

I'm not sure at all how I would go about this though.  Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you simply set `row['number'] = "{:09d}".format(int(row['number']))` before writing `row`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understood. Could you please add sample input and expected output csv file? Zero padding could be done like that `'{0:09d}'.format(1234)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just use the `zfill()` string method on the one field (no need to convert it into a integer first). You can also handle writing the header row in the output file by just calling the `csv.DictWriter.writeheader()` method:

```
import csv,time,string,os,requests
dw = "\\\\network\\folder\\btc.csv"

inv_fields = ["id", "rsl", "number", "color_b4"]

with open(dw, 'rb') as infile, open("c:\\upload\\log.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, inv_fields, extrasaction="ignore")

    r = (dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in r)

    w.writeheader()
    for i, row in enumerate(r, start=1):
        row['id'] = i
        row['number'] = row['number'].zfill(9)  # added
        w.writerow(row)

print "file successfully saved"
```

Comment: I was incredibly confused as to why this wasn't working, until I realized I was testing in Excel and it was removing all the padded zeroes from display upon opening the file :)  Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can conver integers to string first, and then use `zfill` function.

```
>> print str(123).zfill(9)
000000123
>> print str(123).zfill(2)
123
>> print str(123).zfill(3)
123
>> print str(123).zfill(4)
0123
```

Even if you have negative number, you can still use `zfill()` to fill it.

```
>>> print(str(-123).zfill(9))
-00000123
```

Answer (score 1):

As already proposed in the comments, the following works on my machine:

```
# ...
row['number'] = "{:09d}".format(int(row['number']))
w.writerow(row)
```